# I cannot get tables names and columns names from database

Tags: databaselink, sql

I am working with database using OpenSQLConnection-JDBC. I am able to fetch the data perfectly from the tables but I cannot get nor the names of the tables (using SQLTableNames) neither the column names (using SQLColumnNames).
I tried also to work with the help examples; but I got same problem.

what could be the reason?

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection[ 
  JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", 
   "IP/databasename"], 
  "Username" -> "username", "Password" -> "password"]

eventsdata = SQLSelect[
  conn, "tablename",
  SQLColumn["columnname"] == somevalue]
```

where:
IP= Ip address of the database,
databasename=database name that I am connecting to,
tablename=table name which I have it before,
columnname=columns names of the table that I have it before,
somevalue=value so that I can fetch some of the data.

Comment: What command are you using to fetch the data? Can you show us the code that works?

Comment: @mfvonh I have add part of the code that works.

Comment: What output do you get when you try these: `SQLTables[conn]`, `SQLTableNames[conn]`, `SQLTableInformation[conn]`?

Comment: I got all empty list {}.

Comment: Try `SQLExecute[conn, "use tablename"]` and then `SQLTables[conn]`. (with a real table name of course)

Comment: I got JDBC: error when I run SQLExecute[conn, "use tablename"] with my real table name. 
JDBC::error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'table name'at line 1

Comment: I misspoke (miswrote) earlier: can you try `SQLExecute[conn, "use schemaName"]` (not `tableName`)?

Comment: what do you mean by schemaName? if you mean database name, I have tried it now and get same error.

Comment: Yeah, database name. Hm. I am fairly certain I had this problem months ago and I can't remember how to get around it. I think it is specific to MySQL, and it's just something really silly. Does `SQLExecute[conn, "SHOW TABLES"]` work?

Comment: no errors but empty list {}.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, then :/ I'll mull it over and see if something pops up. As I said I'm pretty certain it is something super simple.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use SQL directly. For Oracle databases the following module should work.

```
Module[{dbConn, sqlAct, records},
"SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME like'%your table name%'"// Set[sqlAct, #] &;
OpenSQLConnection["your connection"] // Set[dbConn, #] &;
SQLExecute[dbConn, sqlAct] // Set[records, #] &;
CloseSQLConnection[dbConn];
records
] // MatrixForm // Print;
```